# Transition Content Control for Navigation Frame (WCF RIA Services)

Tags: .net, silverlight, navigation, wcf-ria-services, transitioncontentcontrol

I want to make a transition between my views(pages). But i can't find a way to use the Transitioning Content Control. 
Here is my xaml code.

```
            <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}" 
                          Source="/Home" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
                <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>                        
                    <uriMapper:UriMapper>                            
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                    </uriMapper:UriMapper>                        
                </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>                    
            </navigation:Frame>
        </Border>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically what you need to do is to change the Frame's ControlTemplate by replacing its ContentPresenter with a TransitioningContentControl.

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyFrameControlTemplate" TargetType="navigation:Frame">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
            <toolkit:**TransitioningContentControl**
                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Style="{StaticResource **MyTransitioningContentControlStyle**}"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>


    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Grid.Row="2">
      <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" Template="{StaticResource **MyFrameControlTemplate**}" />
    </Border>
```

And then you need to create a new style for your TransitioningContentControl. In the Visual states I created for you, you can replace them with your desired animations. Please note,

CurrentContentPresentationSite - displays the page which is navigating in
PreviousContentPresentationSite - displays the page which is navigating away

```
    <Style x:Key="**MyTransitioningContentControlStyle**" TargetType="toolkit:TransitioningContentControl">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Transition" Value="DefaultTransition"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:TransitioningContentControl">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PresentationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DefaultTransition">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UpTransition">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="30"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="-30"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="DownTransition">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="CurrentContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-40"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="PreviousContentPresentationSite">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.300" Value="40"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PreviousContentPresentationSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="CurrentContentPresentationSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

There's quite a lot of code in here, please let me know if you have any questions. :)

Comment: Is there any way to create the animations themselves without writing XAML code, ie. using the Blend UI?